# Problem with start controller with roslaunch: controller spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hy everyone,
I'm using ros jade with gazebo 5.2.
I tried to follow  [this](http://www.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control&cat=connect_ros) tutorial. After launching the rrbot_world.launch, I try to do :

```
 roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch
```

I've this response

```
    SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: jade
 * /rosversion: 1.11.16
 * /rrbot/joint1_position_controller/joint: joint1
 * /rrbot/joint1_position_controller/pid/d: 10.0
 * /rrbot/joint1_position_controller/pid/i: 0.01
 * /rrbot/joint1_position_controller/pid/p: 100.0
 * /rrbot/joint1_position_controller/type: effort_controller...
 * /rrbot/joint2_position_controller/joint: joint2
 * /rrbot/joint2_position_controller/pid/d: 10.0
 * /rrbot/joint2_position_controller/pid/i: 0.01
 * /rrbot/joint2_position_controller/pid/p: 100.0
 * /rrbot/joint2_position_controller/type: effort_controller...
 * /rrbot/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /rrbot/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...

NODES
  /
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
  /rrbot/
    controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[rrbot/controller_spawner-1]: started with pid [5768]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [5769]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455881521.257272] [0.000000] Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[WARN] [WallTime: 1455881551.416911] [109.233000] Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
[rrbot/controller_spawner-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/gabriele/.ros/log/33f60b1a-d6fc-11e5-8b0c-e839df8a64f0/rrbot-controller_spawner-1*.log
```

The WARN says that the spawner couldn't not found the controller manager.
I already have this command line  :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-ros-control ros-jade-ros-controllers
```

What's wrong? Could it be a compatibility problem between my gazebo/ros distro?

Then I don't understand what is control_manager. Should it be a directory? Because in my rrbot_control I can't see it. Have I to create it?

Thank you, bye!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12673/problem-with-start-controller-with-roslaunch:-controller-spawner-couldn%27t-find-the-expected-controller_manager-ros-interface/) by [gabri89](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2451/gabri89/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello again :)

In [this tutorial, section *Install gazebo_ros_pkgs*](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing#Installgazebo_ros_pkgs), it says that there is no `ros-jade-gazebo-ros-control` debian package released for now. Without this, you can't run simulations using ros_control in Gazebo.

What you can do now is clone the [gazebo_ros_pkgs repository](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs) and compile the `gazebo_ros_control` package, so you can run your simulation.

---

Originally posted by [longforgotten](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1313/longforgotten/) with karma: 46 on 2016-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2